# Assigning a directory thumbnail image for an MP4 in Android?

Tags: android, thumbnails, mp4

I'm trying to assign a specific thumbnail image to represent the media file (mp4) within the android directory.  By default, I believe android will use the first frame.

I've tried metadata/tags to no avail.

Please let me know if you have a solution, and I will be forever in your gratitude.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/

This is part of the code I used:

```
String filepath = "/yourFilePathHere/yourFileNameHere.ext";
File sourceFile = new File ( filepath );

IsoBufferWrapper isoBufferWrapper = new IsoBufferWrapperImpl( sourceFile );
IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(isoBufferWrapper);
isoFile.parse();

AppleItemListBox appleItemListBox = (AppleItemListBox) IsoFileConvenienceHelper.get(isoFile, "moov/udta/meta/ilst");
AppleCoverBox coverBox = (AppleCoverBox) IsoFileConvenienceHelper.get (appleItemListBox, AppleCoverBox.TYPE);

List<Box> dataBoxes = coverBox.getBoxes();
byte[] coverBoxByte = null;
if (dataBoxes != null && dataBoxes.size() > 0) {
    AppleDataBox dataBox = (AppleDataBox)dataBoxes.get(0);
    coverBoxByte = dataBox.getContent();
}

Bitmap icon = null;
if (coverBoxByte != null){
    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(coverBoxByte, 0, coverBoxByte.length);
}
```